# Add php code in jsp file

Tags: php, jsp, integration

I have a code like this:

```
<object>
. . .
<param name="url" value="http://box.net/test/datefile.pdf">
. . .
</object>
```

I want to add php code in the value of the `param` tag.
(i.e `value="http://box.net/test/datefile.pdf"` this should be replaced by php code)

If the pdf file is called as test.pdf how to add in the above jsp code using php?

Thanks -
Haan

Comment: Maybe you should consider clarifying your question.  I'm now really confused and not sure if I need to delete my answer or not.  What's the deal?

Comment: "...in the above jsp code..." - all you have shown so far is HTML.  Are you sure this is a jsp page?  If so, why are you trying to add PHP instead of Java?

Comment: @jmorth253 - got my answer from Jason. thanks for ur comments too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Params are easy - just add

```
?param=value&param2=value
```

Like this:

```
<param name="url" value="http://box.net/test/datefile.pdf?param=value&param2=value">
```

I assume that PDF file there is actually a PHP script right?

Comment: it worked well as u said. thanks a lot. this is wat i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put PHP in a JSP page.  I'm not even sure why you would want to.  Just Google whatever you're trying to do in the param in JSP.  The PHP you want to use can't possibly be that long if you want to embed it.